# Unable to remove bullet points in CSS navigation bar

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

I have a navigation bar in styled using CSS. I can't seem to remove the bullet points using list-style-type: none. Or override it with !important; function. This is what my html and css look like. This works fine in chrome but the error shows up in firefox and IE.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index1.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="read.html">Read</a>
<ul class="drop-content">
<li><a href="#">Latest Issue</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Prose</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Poetry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Transalations</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="research.html">Research</a>
<ul class="drop-content">
<li><a href="#">Publications</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Deaprtments</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="newsandevents.html">News and Events</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   .menu {list-style-type: none;
   height: 50px;
   display: block;
   font-family: Helvetica;}

   li {float: left;
   }




   a {display: block;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;   
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color:#009899;}
```

Comment: add `list-style: none'` to `li` selector too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have list-style-type in the `.menu` class tag which is a div (list-style-type is a style for `<li>` tags not divs)

change

```
 li {float: left;
   }
```

to

```
 li {float: left;
   list-style-type:none;
   }
```

```css
   .menu {
   height: 50px;
   display: block;
   font-family: Helvetica;}

   li {float: left;
   list-style-type:none;
   }
   a {display: block;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;   
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color:#009899;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index1.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="read.html">Read</a>
<ul class="drop-content">
<li><a href="#">Latest Issue</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Prose</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Poetry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Transalations</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="research.html">Research</a>
<ul class="drop-content">
<li><a href="#">Publications</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Deaprtments</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="newsandevents.html">News and Events</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add list-style:none to the li tag

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index1.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="read.html">Read</a>
<ul class="drop-content">
<li><a href="#">Latest Issue</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Prose</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Poetry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Transalations</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="research.html">Research</a>
<ul class="drop-content">
<li><a href="#">Publications</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Deaprtments</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="newsandevents.html">News and Events</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {list-style-type: none;
   height: 50px;
   display: block;
   font-family: Helvetica;}

   li {float: left;
   list-style:none;
   }




   a {display: block;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;   
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color:#009899;}
```

Demo Link: https://jsfiddle.net/hellosrini/zy5z5gdh/

Answer (score 1):

add `list-style: none;` to your second `CSS` selector, `li {}`